# Complex numbers 3D array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, complex-numbers

How do I define three dimensional array of complex numbers dynamically in C so that I can access in `[i] [j] [k]` notations which is handy in accessing arrays?

Comment: Here' `i` and `j` represents real and imaginary part of the complex number, right?

Comment: No [i][j][k] are three indices of the 3D array. suppose if want to access 1st element of array A then I will be indexing it as A[0][0][0] .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending *[Bob__](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4944425/bob)*'s [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39182667/694576) to have the array allocated on the heap instead of on the stack:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex.h>


int main(void) 
{
  size_t n = 2, m = 3, o = 4;

  double complex (*pa)[n][m][o] = malloc(sizeof *pa);
  if (NULL == pa)
  {
    perror("malloc() failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  (*pa)[1][2][3] = 1.0 + 0.5*I;

  printf("%f + %fi\n", creal((*pa)[1][2][3]), cimag((*pa)[1][2][3]));

  free(pa);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) This seems to work for me I will try it out :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a VLA, for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex.h>

int main(void) {
    size_t n = 2,
           m = 3,
           o = 4;

    double complex a[n][m][o];

    a[1][2][3] = 1.0 + 0.5*I;

    printf("%f + %fi\n", creal(a[1][2][3]), cimag(a[1][2][3]));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank for the reply:) I have exactly this style in my code and it works for small arrays but I have say very big array then I end getting segmentation fault (core dumped) error with this :(